# MacOS upgrade deletes embedded postgres

Tags: mac-osx, postgresql

An app for MacOS embeds postgres in the application bundle. The user's app data is stored in a separate path using a Tablespace config.

A recent upgrade of MacOS appears to delete the embedded directory.  Is there any way to restore the user's data with only the data files stored in the Tablespace path?

Comment: What data you have after update?

Comment: None. We have determined that the entire directory is deleted, including the data. In our case, the directory tree looks like this:
`appname
-- Contents
--- MacOS
---- Postgres
----- version
------ data`

Comment: We were able to confirm the problem with apple dev support. We should not have placed postgres within the app bundle without greater attention to the digital signature on the bundle.

Comment: You could add as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to confirm the problem with apple dev support. We should not have placed postgres within the app bundle without greater attention to the digital signature on the bundle.